# Collision detection for individual objects in a list Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I want to have it so that a single game object from a list is destroyed when it hits the ground. So far I am able to spawn random prefabs in set spawn locations in the scene successfully, but I am having trouble implementing the collision detection for when they fall to the ground. I have tried both raycasting and OnCollisionEnter but neither is working, the collision is not being detected. I am missing something but not sure what. Below is my attempt with OnCollisionEnter:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectSpawner : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> prefabObjects;
    public List<GameObject> locations;
    public List<GameObject> spawnedObjects;

    void Start()
    {
        //create empty list of spawned objects
        spawnedObjects = new List<GameObject>();

        SpawnObject(RandomObjects());
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    void SpawnObject(GameObject obj)
    {
        GameObject newObject = Instantiate(obj, transform.position, Quaternion.identity );

        spawnedObjects.Add(newObject);
    }

     GameObject RandomObjects()
     {

        int rand = Random.Range(0, prefabObjects.Count);
            
        return prefabObjects[rand];

     }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < spawnedObjects.Count; i++){
            GameObject obj = spawnedObjects[i];

            if (collision.collider.tag == "Ground"){
                Debug.Log("Hit ground");
                spawnedObjects.Remove(obj);
                Destroy(obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)` method is in the wrong place, you dont want the `ObjectSpawner` itself to collide but the instancianted `obj`'s. Place a new script on your prefabs and implement `OnCollisionEnter` there. For the method to trigger, be sure to set up colliders and rigidbodies correctly. Your prefabs and the ground should have colliders and either one of these a non-kinematic rigidbody too.